# Practical implementation of Hamiltonian Evolution

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-gate, hhl-algorithm, hamiltonian-simulation

Following from [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/3743/error-simulation-of-quantum-algorithm-for-linear-systems-of-equations-for-4), I tried to look at the cited [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2232v2) in order to simulate and solve that same problem... without success. Mainly, I still fail to understand how the authors managed to simulate the Hamiltonian evolution through the circuit shown at the bottom of Fig.4. Even exponentiating classically the matrix I do not get values of the gates shown in the Quirk circuit that @Blue linked along his question.

I tried to look at the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.5625) in which the Group Leader Optimization algorithm is explained, but I still have troubles understanding how do they assign the rotation angles to the different gates.

Comment: Good question! Some of those rotation angle values are definitely wrong. @Nelimee tried them out in [his program](https://github.com/nelimee/quantum-tools). Have a look at `optim_hamil.py`. A practical way to get the correct rotation angle values/coefficients is to use some sort of multivariate optimization algorithm. Nelimee used the `scipy.optimize` module for that purpose. However, I would like to personally understand the Group Leader Optimization Algorithm properly too. The paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.2242 is too vague!

Comment: The point is that from what I understood they are using genetic algorithms to find the optimal configuration to represent a given quantum subroutine, which already strikes me as odd honestly.

Comment: You can recover the matrices exponentials with [this script](https://gist.github.com/nelimee/31c66e6b1e5586275f82d960c3b2020a). And you understood correctly, they use a genetic algorithm (which is a kind of optimisation algorithm) to find **a good** (and not **the optimal**) gate decomposition that implements a unitary matrix that is close to the one we want.

Comment: Thanks for the script! However, with this you obtain directly the values of the exponentiated matrix, which can be directly implemented in Quirk, I was rather trying to understan how they manage to simulate such matrix with the gates they provided in the figure, because I also tried to compute  the circuit to see the final matrix, but I end up having something totally different. I do not exclude to have made some miscalculations though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why/how the authors of that paper do what they do. However, here's how I'd go about it for this special case (and it is a very special case):

You can write the Hamiltonian as a Pauli decomposition
$$
A=15\mathbb{I}\otimes\mathbb{I}+9Z\otimes X+5X\otimes Z-3Y\otimes Y.
$$
**Update:** It should be $+3Y\otimes Y$. But I don't want to redraw all my diagrams etc., so I'll leave the negative sign.

Now, it is interesting to note that every one of these terms commutes. So, that means that
$$
e^{iA\theta}=e^{15i\theta}e^{9i\theta Z\otimes X}e^{5i\theta X\otimes Z}e^{-3i\theta Y\otimes Y}.
$$
You could work out how to simulate each of these steps individually, but let me make one further observation first: these commuting terms are the stabilizers of the 2-qubit cluster state. That may or may not mean anything to you, but it tells me that a smart thing to do is apply a controlled-phase gate.
$$
CP\cdot A\cdot CP=15\mathbb{I}\otimes\mathbb{I}+9\mathbb{I}\otimes X+5X\otimes \mathbb{I}-3X\otimes X.
$$
(You may want to check the sign of the last term. I didn't compute it carefully.)
So, if we start and end our sequence with controlled-phase gates, then 2 of the terms are easy to get right: we rotate the first qubit about the $x$ axis by an angle $5\theta$, and the second qubit about the $x$ axis by an angle $9\theta$.

The only thing we are left to get right is the $X\otimes X$ rotation. If you think about the structure of $e^{-3i\theta X\otimes X}$, this is like an $x$ rotation on the basis states $\{|00\rangle,|11\rangle\}$, and another one on $\{|01\rangle,|10\rangle\}$. A controlled-not converts these bases into the single-qubit bases controlled off the target qubit. But since both implement the same controlled-rotation but controlled off opposite values, we can just remove the control. Thus, the overall circuit is:
[image]
This simplifies slightly by combining the two controlled-gates at the end:
[image]
Note that I have not included the global phase term here because that's not the sensible way to do it. When you make controlled-($e^{iA\theta}$), you apply the "global phase" as a $z$ rotation on the control qubit.

Comment: Hi, do you know any textbook or any paper which discusses the general algorithm for decomposing the Hamiltonian into Pauli gates? I only found [this website](https://michaelgoerz.net/notes/decomposing-two-qubit-hamiltonians-into-pauli-matrices.html), but it doesn't explain the logic behind the decomposition nor the general algorithm for larger matrices (if it exists).

Comment: @Blue The simplest method is based on a Trotter-Suzuki decomposition. Those key words should hopefully provide a fruitful search. However, there are newer, much more efficient, algorithms. I'll need to dig out a reference...

Comment: @Blue Here's a talk that gives a fair introduction+overview, and contains links to some of the relevant papers: http://www.bristol.ac.uk/media-library/sites/maths/events/2015/dominicberry-talk.pdf

Comment: I was a bit confused by the second Pauli decomposition and asked a question regarding that [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4449/how-does-the-stated-pauli-decomposition-for-operatornamecp-cdot-a-cdot-cp-a). If you get time, do please consider answering it!